# How to select a radio button in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I've been having some trouble editing my radio buttons via CSS because I can't figure out how to properly refer to them.  My code for them is as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 class="testTitle"> Letter Height</h1>

<h2 class="testIns">Press the buttons to make it shorter or taller!</h2>  

<div id="testBox">
<img src="images/testImages/height/heightMid.gif"> 
</div>

<form method="get" action="width.php" class="testAns" id="heightAns">
<input type="radio" name="height" value="short" onchange="ChangeDisplay('short');">Shorter height
<input type="radio" name="height" value="mid" onchange="ChangeDisplay('mid');">Normal height
<input type="radio" name="height" value="tall" onchange="ChangeDisplay('tall');">Taller height
<br>
<h2 class="confirm">Does this look good?  If so, please click the <span class="testSubmit">"Submit"</span> button.</h2>

<span class="submit"><input type="submit"></span>
</form>
</div>
```

So the radio buttons are inside a div called "wrapper", and inside a form with class="testAns" and id="heightAns".  I want to be able to edit the radio buttons and the text around them, but the only thing I can get to work is:

```
.testAns {code;}
```

But this highlights the entire form instead of just the radio buttons.  I've already tried a few combinations of the class and form, etc. but I can't seem to get them to work.  What's strange is that the submit button's CSS is working just fine, which is part of the form, class and ID.  It's working code is:

```
form input[type=submit] {code;}
```

Can anyone give me some insight?

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers offer limited styling of the radio button so some styles may not appear to do anything. The code you need in css to catch radio inputs is `input[type=radio] {margin: 10px;}`

You can apply extra or alternative styles when the radio button is checked by using `input[type=radio]:checked {margin: 5px;}`

Comment: I would have said that too... but take a look at that codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qctaL

Comment: Nevermind... It seems that it's just that neither border nor color can be applied to a radio input (why??). But a test with margin proves that the selector is indeed correct.

Comment: So then I'm gonna go ahead and assume that the problem here is the styling and not the selector (the OP probably had it right). Then I'd recommend taking a look at <label> with which you can control a radio input and style the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

add the class to the radio buttons them selves instead of the wrapping div.

**form.html**

```
<form method="get" action="width.php" id="heightAns">
    <input class="testAns" type="radio" name="height" value="short" onchange="ChangeDisplay('short');">Shorter height
    <input class="testAns" type="radio" name="height" value="mid" onchange="ChangeDisplay('mid');">Normal height
    <input class="testAns" type="radio" name="height" value="tall" onchange="ChangeDisplay('tall');">Taller height
    <br>
    <h2 class="confirm">Does this look good?  If so, please click the <span class="testSubmit">"Submit"</span> button.</h2>

    <span class="submit"><input type="submit"></span>
</form>
```

**style.css**

```
.testAnd {
    css code...
}
```

Comment: and then refer to it as: ".testAns input[type=radio]" ?

Comment: no just .testAns aka the class name, which can be anything you want

Comment: I tried this out and it doesn't seem to be working.  I took out the class and id from the form tag, and placed class names called "heightAns" into each radio.  When I refer to it as ".heightAns" in my CSS I get nothing.

Comment: figured it out using Chrome's developer tools.  putting the the class inside the radio buttons did the trick, but selecting the actual radio button itself used "input.className" instead of just ".className".  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
input[type=radio] {
    /* some code */
}
```